# Change `lxlock` login screen in Debian Stretch LXDE

Tags: debian, login, lxde

After having trouble with my python I had to reinstall my LXDE with

```
apt-get install task-lxde-desktop
```

All my settings remained working except one I don't know if it depends on the reinstallation or a setting I have to make.

LXDE has its own login screen on startup. Before the reinstallation I had a shortcut on my suspend key to invoke `lxlock` and I had the login screen again.

After the reinstallation I have the same shortcut remaining but I see this aweful login screen from `xscreensaver` which I'm not able to get rid of.

My `xscreensaver` settings are strict deactivated. I don't need the screensaver.

So how to get rid of the XScreenSaver login and go to the LXDE login?

---

**Edit (2017-12-19)**

I don't want to remove the XScreenSaver package, while this causes `lxlock` to be removed too. I just wan't to change the login screen displayed. Remove XScreensaver login and show the LXDE startup login instead.

Additionally I found out that the menu `Logout / Screen Lock` causes the same login screen. So it's a generally configuration somewhere on my system I have to find and to alterate.

---

**Edit ( 2017-12-19)**

After diggin' around I found out I was wrong with the assumption`lxlock` will be removed with `xscreensaver`. So I did what @ipor-sircer mentioned and removed `xscreensaver`.

`man lxlock` shows that lxlock invokes

```
light-locker
xscreensaver
gnome-screensaver
slock
xlock
i3lock
```

in the shown order.

After the removal of `xscreensaver` nothing happens while invoking `lxlock`. I found out, that `light-locker` is the only package installed. But I didn't manage to get it running manually.

Comment: `apt purge xscreensaver`

Comment: Please read the edit I made. Should sort some needs out.